# Duplication in data while scraping data using Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, duplicates

**python**

I am using scrapy to scrape data from a website, where i want to scrape graphic cards title,price and whether they are in stock or not. The problem is my code is looping twice and instead of having **10** products I am getting **20**.

```
import scrapy
    
class ThespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Thespider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.czone.com.pk/graphic-cards-pakistan-ppt.154.aspx?page=2']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        data = {}
        cards = response.css('div.row')
        for card in cards:
            for c in card.css('div.product'):
                data['Title'] =  c.css('h4 a::text').getall()
                data['Price'] =  c.css('div.price span::text').getall()
                data['Stock'] = c.css('div.product-stock span.product-data::text').getall()
                yield data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a nested for loop when one isn't necessary.

Each card can be captured by the CSS selector `response.css('div.product')`

### Code Example

```
def parse(self, response):
    data = {}
    cards = response.css('div.product')
    for card in cards:
        data['Title'] =  card.css('h4 a::text').getall()
        data['Price'] =  card.css('div.price span::text').getall()
        data['Stock'] = card.css('div.product-stock span.product-data::text').getall()
        yield data
```

### Additional Information

- Use `get()` instead of `getall()`. The output you get is a list, you'll probably want a string which is what `get()` gives you.
- If you're thinking about multiple pages, an items dictionary may be better than yielding a dictionary. Invariably there will be the thing you need to alter and an items dictionary gives you more flexibility to do this.